# How do you increment a number(value) to a XML node every time?

Tags: c#, xml, post, integer

Basically, I have been having trouble with incrementing a integer to a XML node. I have a node called `userID` and it is acting like a login system for each user.

However it always seems to count each user as the `userID` of 1.

I would like this to increment up for each user so 1,2,3,4 etc.

I know it needs to read the previous number/value of the previous user but not sure how.

Comment: Do you have code that shows what you've tried so far and how its failing?

Comment: There's not enough information here. Are you saying that you have an XML node with text/value of *n* and you want to change it to *n* + 1?

Comment: xwriter.writeStartElement("UserID");         xwriter.WriteString(userID.ToString());                          string UserIDVariable = userID.ToString();         writer.writeendelement();

Comment: That would look at lot better in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Convert your xml file to a datatable and loop it. If you need code then Show what you have done. Then we can assist you.

Comment: While, I agree that this is about the only answer that can be given to a question like this now, it is in fact, not an answer.  At best its a comment.

Comment: I have a variable set up as    userID int = 0      userID ++

Comment: please provide your code - might be the class where you have implemented and the xml file. You can edit your question and Add those stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increment `UserId` with number of user nodes already existing (or +1 of it).

e.g.

```
newUserID = UserNodes.Count();
```

The problem is with deletions. You could instead maintain an attribute at root level to remember the last used `userID` and increment every time.